# Conjugate of powers equals powers of conjugates?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I read a proof recently that used the fact that $\overline{i^i}=\overline{i}^\overline{i}$. It made me think:

> Is it true that $\overline{z^z}=\overline{z}^\overline{z}$ for any complex number $z$?

I have seen proofs that $\overline{z^n}=\overline{z}^n$ where $n$ is a positive whole number, but I wonder here about complex numbers in general.

Can anyone point me to a good source or, if it is simple, provide a brief proof or hint?

Comment: What is your definition of $z^z$?

Comment: It sounds like it is not a trivial thing then. I still don't understand how the proof referenced at the beginning of my question used the fact it did. I'm not in complex analysis or anything so I imagine this must be beyond me.

Comment: Well, the issue is that there is actually no standard definition of $z^z$ at all--complex exponentiation is not well-defined in most cases.  It is really an abuse of notation to write $i^i$ at all unless you have chosen a specific (and necessarily somewhat arbitrary) definition.